# Copying each row to new table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

while copying each row to new table, , I am running into "object reference not set to an instace of object" in the line of "temp[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);". Here note that dr.itemarray is not an empty array.

```
    DataTable dt;
    DataTable[] temp=null;

    dt =(DataTable)Session["datatable"];

    temp = new DataTable[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            temp[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the array but not the `DataTable` in it:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        temp[i] = new DataTable(); // <--------
        temp[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, i must admit that i don't understand your code. I assume you want to copy every row from the originqal table into it's own `DataTable`. Then you have one loop too much:

```
for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    temp[i] = new DataTable();
    temp[i].ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.. Here i have already initialized temp = new DataTable[dt.Rows.Count];

Comment: @user3104758: Yes, you have initialized the array itself but not every table in it. Note that i've edited my answer.

Comment: @user3104758_ Have you noticed that i've edited my answer and also provided a different approach?

Comment: I tried your second code snippet.. but still same error comes out in the "temp[i].ImportRow(row)" line, despite it has 12 items in its itemsarray

Comment: @user3104758: You have initialized the array but you have not initialized the `DataTables`. So the array's length is 12 but it does not contain 12 initialized tables, all are `Nothing`. That's why i have use `... new DataTable`. Use the debugger and look into `temp` and you'll see that it contains only `Nothing`s.

Comment: In debugging, it shows temp is null although i have initialized as you said.